# PYthon 3.4 question mark in text file

Tags: file, python-3.x, text

I have a problem: I am using Python 3.4.
My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

f = open('D:/TMP/Test.txt', 'w')
str = "Why ist there no question mark ??? "
f.write(str +'\n')
f.close()
```

Very simple, but the result is:

Why ist there no question mark

Thanks for your help...

Best regards
Geosucher

Comment: Working fine for me. Can you please provide the return value of `f.write()`?

Comment: Have you checked `Test.txt` in some hexeditor? I mean is this the case of mismatching encoding for read/write or just f.write() not writing those symbols?

Comment: Ok, the hexcode from the end is: 6D 61 72 6B 20 9D 9D 9D 20
The editor means: "mark     "